# Override class method behavior through unit testing iOS

Tags: ios, unit-testing

I have class `ServerHandler` with one class method:

```
+ (void) sendRequestEventToServer:(MyData*) requestDataForCaching                   
                        onSuccess:(void (^)(void))successBlock;
```

This method is responsible to send HTTP request to Server.
I call this method from dozen places in my program.

My goal is to get what data is sent to server therefore I need to write test where I override this method and instead to send `MyData` to server my program should send it to Test class.

I tried several approaches but none of them  works.

```
@interface ServerHandler (TestSupport)
+ (void) mockSendRequestEventToServer:(MyData*) requestDataForCaching onSuccess:(void (^)(void))successBlock;
@end

@implementation ServerHandler (TestSupport)

+ (void) mockSendRequestEventToServer:(MyData*) requestDataForCaching  onSuccess:(void (^)(void))successBlock
{
    NSLog(@"mockSendRequestEventToServer");
}

+ (void)load {
    Method original = class_getClassMethod([ServerHandler class], @selector(sendRequestEventToServer));
    Method mocked   = class_getClassMethod([ServerHandler class], @selector(mockSendRequestEventToServer));
    method_exchangeImplementations(original, mocked);
}
@end
```

Now I run the test:

```
@implementation ServerTalkerTests

- (void)setUp {
    [super setUp];    
    [ServerHandler load];
}


- (void) test_serverTalker {

     __block BOOL isRunning = YES;

    [[MyProgram shared] start]; 

     // ...
    NSDate *timeout = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10];
    do {
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode
                                 beforeDate:timeout];
    } while (isRunning);

}

@end
```

When I run the program through `[[MyProgram shared] start];`  It should call mocked `[ServerHandler sendRequestEventToServer]` but it calls original method

What Im doing wrong?

I also tried with OCMock

Comment: What you get if you call it directly `[ServerHandler mockSendRequestEventToServer:nil completion:nil];` ?

Comment: it calls properly, but if i call directly `[ServerHandler sendRequestEventToServer:nil completion:nil];` - calls original implementation

Answer (score 1):

Follow the code below, should execute your methods properly.

```
+ (void)load {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        Class class = [self class];

        SEL originalSelector = @selector(sendRequestEventToServer);
        SEL mockedSelector = @selector(mockSendRequestEventToServer);

        Method originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, originalSelector);
        Method mockedMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, mockedSelector);


        BOOL didAddMethod =
            class_addMethod(class,
                originalSelector,
                method_getImplementation(mockedMethod),
                method_getTypeEncoding(mockedMethod));

        if (didAddMethod) {
            class_replaceMethod(class,
                mockedSelector,
                method_getImplementation(originalMethod),
                method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod));
        } else {
            method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, mockedMethod);
        }
    });
}
```

**Source** - [Method Swizzling](http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/)

**Update** - Using **[jrswizzle](https://github.com/rentzsch/jrswizzle)** I solved it

Add your new method in the same class ie `ServerHandler` not in a category, and just call the following method

```
[ServerHandler jr_swizzleClassMethod:@selector(sendRequestEventToServer) withClassMethod:@selector(mockSendRequestEventToServer) error:nil];
```

Then call the original method

```
[ServerHandler sendRequestEventToServer:nil completion:nil];
```

The above should work fine.

Cheers.

Comment: I got `didAddMethod = YES` but still when I call `sendRequestEventToServer` it enters to original implementation

Comment: The problem is with the static method call, it doesn't recognize the method exchange because it runs on a different instance, I changed the call to non-static functions it works fine..

Comment: Are you sure about `class_getInstanceMethod(class, originalSelector)` ? it should be `class_getClassMethod(class, originalSelector);` no?

Comment: From your description, `[ServerHandler jr_swizzleClassMethod:@selector(sendRequestEventToServer) withClassMethod:@selector(mockSendRequestEventToServer) error:nil];` should be added to original class `ServerHandler`. That mean - I need to modify my application only to be able to test it, right?